# Python: How to show the file type and full name in search algorithm?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a search algorithm that can find any file on the computer with that in it's name but i can't figure out how to get it to show what type of file it is and it's full name

```
import os
a=str(input('File Name: '))
i=0
for path,dirs,files in os.walk('C:\\'):
   for name in files:
      if a in name:
         i=i+1
         c=[path,'\\',a]
         c=''.join(c)
         print('File Location is',c)
      else:
         i=i+1
print(i,'Files Scanned')
```

Comment: Please clarify the question and show the current output, vs the expected output.  What *exactly* is the issue?

Comment: Ok so basically i want to find every file with the name File Locator in it from only part of it's name
This is my output
File Name: File Loc
File Location is C:\Users\me\Documents\Python Code\File Loc
The output i want is
C:\Users\me\Documents\Python Code\File Locator.py

Comment: You define `c=[path,'\\',a]`. You want `c=[path,'\\',name]`. Even better: Use `c = fr'{path}\{name}'` and drop the line with `c=''.join(c)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
import glob

for name in glob.glob('c:\\'):
   
         print( name)#lists all the files, Dont run this code your pc might crash. Use it in search algorithm.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).